# Find element by data-id

Tags: jquery, html

How do I, with the clearest syntax, find the second element with the data-id `411` ?

```
<div data-id="410">Yo</div>
<div data-id="411">No</div>
<div data-id="412">Mm</div>
```

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$("div[data-id=411]").text("Hello")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-id="410">Yo</div>
<div data-id="411">No</div>
<div data-id="412">Mm</div>
```

Something as simple as this should work. Jason is right though, the jQuery website has some great documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You want to assign a class name to the elements you are searching from, so that it's not looking at the whole document.

```
<div class="search">
<div data-id="410">Yo</div>
<div data-id="411">No</div>
<div data-id="412">Mm</div>
</div>

var element = $('.search').find("div[data-id='411']");
```

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket